# How to assign ContactEmail and ContactPhone while creating a Case

Tags: apex

I am creating a **case** and I have a **contactID**.

My requiremnet is to create a **case** and assign **ContactEmail** and **ContactPhone** by using the **contactID**.

I am storing `Contact Email (custEmail) and contact Phone (custPhone)` in a getter setter variable.

I know we can assign ContactEmail and ContactPhone to Case like below:

```
Case.ContactId = contactId;
Case.Contact.Email = custEmail;
Case.Contact.Phone = custPhone;
```

But I am getting null Pointer excaption on  `Case.Contact.Email`, because Case.Contact is null.

Is there any other way I can assign getter and setter value to **Case's ContactEmail and ContactPhone** while inserting the same **Case**.

Comment: If your contact record with contactId has already email & phone defined in it then what is the need of assigning again? Do you mean that you want to update that contact with "custEmail" Email & "custPhone" Phone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is not the right way to assign value to parent objects field,

```
Case.Contact.Email = custEmail;
Case.Contact.Phone = custPhone;
```

If you want to update your contact email & Phone then it can be done as below,

```
List<Contact> lstContact = [select id,Email,Phone from Contact where id =:contactId];
if(lstContact!=null && lstContact.size()>0){
     lstContact[0].Email = custEmail;
     lstContact[0].Phone = custPhone;
     update lstContact[0];
}
```